# Uncaught TypeError in javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, css, this

I've been trying to use the `this` keyword to fetch a `dataset` but I keep getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined`, In the below script what I'm trying to achieve is that whenever a button is clicked then it displays certain content and hide all other things

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Show Page</title>
        <script>
            function showPage(division){
                document.querySelectorAll('h1').style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector(divsion).style.display = 'block';
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
                document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
                    button.onclick = () => {
                        showPage(this.dataset.page);
                    } 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <button data-page="page1">Page1</button>
        <button data-page="page2">Page2</button>
        <button data-page="page3">Page3</button>
        <h1 id="page1">This is page1</h1>
        <h1 id="page2">This is page2</h1>
        <h1 id="page3">This is page3</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error means that `this.dataset` is `undefined`.

Comment: You are using arrow functions for all your callbacks so the `this` is not going to be a reference to the dom element(s) that triggered the event like it would when using a normal function expression

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('h1').style.display` doesn’t exist. See [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/4642212). Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `function() {}` in your click handler, to be in the correct context. Arrow functions keep the surrounding context:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.page);
  }
});
```

```html
<button data-page="page1">Page1</button>
<button data-page="page2">Page2</button>
<button data-page="page3">Page3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `arrow function` then `this` will not contain the current element, you need to pass a `parameter(event)` in the `function`, get its `current target` and then get the properties.

```js
function showPage(division) {
  document.querySelectorAll('h1').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector(divsion).style.display = 'block';
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = (e) => { // pass a parameter here
      //showPage(e.currentTarget.dataset.page); // get current target of event and its property.
      console.clear();
      console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.page); // output on console
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Show Page</title>

</head>

<body>
  <button data-page="page1">Page1</button>
  <button data-page="page2">Page2</button>
  <button data-page="page3">Page3</button>
  <h1 id="page1">This is page1</h1>
  <h1 id="page2">This is page2</h1>
  <h1 id="page3">This is page3</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

See if it helps you.

Comment: You can also use a `normal function` instead of an `arrow function` as @blex suggests.